# Getting filthy meaning

Tags: meaning, american-english

I get filthy when that liquor get into me
What does it mean?
Does “ getting filthy” mean getting dirty or 
Getting decisve in that sentence?

Comment: A quick look at a [dictionary entry](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Filthy) will give you your own answer (hint: meaning 2 in the first three entries). Edit the question if you need more information, please.

Comment: I have no idea how "filthy" and "decisive" could be compared, nor what your whole Question is about, nor how it could belong here…

Still, it's possible "I get filthy when that liquor get into me" might mean "I do (very) naughty things when I'm drunk".